# MVVMLight how to get access to MainViewModel instance

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'd need to access MainViewModel's instance from MainWindow.xaml.cs. Is it possible?

pom

Comment: Answering to myself: ViewModelLocator.MainStatic

Answer (score 0):

DataContext is a reference of ViewModel. So if you want to access and you're in MainWindow.cs, you'll use "this.Datacontext"

Comment: True, but I think ViewModelLocator.MainStatic is cleaner. Thank you for an answer!